# Как сделать отступ от border?

Tags: html, css

Есть блок с `border-top: 20px solid #222;`. Как всегда этот border прикреплен к верхней границе. Можно ли сделать отступ с верху для `border`?

Comment: В основном отступы делают с помощью *padding* и *margin* вам соответственно `padding-top`  и `margin-top`. Лучше margin - это внешний отступ.

Comment: Вы не так поняли. Нужно именно сделать отступ для border. Т.е. сдвинуть его от верхней границе и чтобы это не повлияло на содержимое блока

Comment: Тогда padding - это отступ внутри блока

Comment: Или даже внутренний блок, ему маргин от внешнего с бордером.

Comment: Сделайте два елемента и назначьте одному border а второй вложите в первый. Всётаки со-стороны не понятна проблема.

Comment: А лучше приложите код того, что есть и скрин, того, что нужно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока два варианта:

1. `margin` или `padding`
2. Вложить в блок с `border` внутренний блок, ему выдать `margin-top`.